# general member of a linear system

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $|L|$ be a linear system of a quasi protective variety X, and Z a subvariety of X. If Z is not contained in BS($|L|$), is it true that Z is not contained in a general member of $|L|$ ?

Comment: You can check whether a section of $\mathcal{O}_X(L)$ vanishes at the generic point of $Z$, right? That looks like a closed, proper condition on $H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X(L))$.